# How to use $this inside php closure?

Tags: php, closures

I have code like this:

```
class Foo {
   var $callbacks = array();
   function __construct() {
      $this->callbacks[] = function($arg) {
         return $this->bar($arg);
      };
   }
   function bar($arg) {
      return $arg * $arg;
   }
}
```

and I would like to use $this inside closures, I've try to add `use ($this)` but this throw error:

```
Cannot use $this as lexical variable
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Is it `5.3` or less?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `$this` as this is an explicit reserved variable for the class inside reference to the class instance itself. Make a copy to `$this` and then pass it to the `use` language construct.

```
class Foo {
   var $callbacks = array();
   function __construct() {
      $class = $this;
      $this->callbacks[] = function($arg) use ($class) {
         return $class->bar($arg);
      };
   }
   function bar($arg) {
      return $arg * $arg;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give $this to another var and use that.

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        $another = $this;
        return function() use($another)
        {
            print_r($another);
        };
    }
}
```