# Rewriting a recursive anonymous function in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function, arrow-functions, php-7.4

There is the following anonymous recursive function:

```
$f = function($n) use (&$f) {
    return ($n == 1) ? 1 : $n * $f($n - 1);
};

echo $f(5); // 120
```

I try to rewrite to version 7.4, but there is an error, please tell me what I'm missing?

```
$f = fn($n) => ($n == 1) ? 1 : $n * $f($n - 1);
echo $f(5);
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: f
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use arrow functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657135/how-to-use-arrow-functions-in-php)

Comment: You need the `use()` modifier so you can refer to the external variable `$f`.

Comment: I don't know whether this should be closed as dup or answered, so I actually appreciate your feedback. Please mark as accepted if it helped. There is also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658110/1839439

Comment: As stated in the linked question, arrow functions will capture outside variables *by value*. But the the original anonymous function is is capturing by reference. I don't think there's an equivalent with arrow functions.

Comment: @Barmar, that is, without `use()` it will not be possible to use in the new syntax?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just like Barmar said, you can't use `$f` from the outside scope, because when the implicit binding takes place `$f` is still undefined.

There is nothing stopping you from passing it later as a parameter.

```
$f = fn($f, $n) => $n == 1 ? 1 : $n * $f($f, $n - 1);
echo $f($f, 5); // 120
```

The way arrow functions work, is that during definition time they will use by-value binding of the outer scope's variables.

> As already mentioned, arrow functions use by-value variable binding. This is roughly equivalent to performing a `use($x)` for every variable `$x` used inside the arrow function. - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2

The assignment of the closure to the variable `$f` happens after closure's definition and the variable `$f` is undefined prior to it.

As far as I am aware, there isn't any mechanism to bind by reference while defining arrow functions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can rewrite the function as an arrow function.

An arrow function will capture the value of any external variables *by value* at the time the function is created. But `$f` won't have a value until after the function is created and the variable is assigned.

The original anonymous function solves this problem by capturing a reference to the variable with `use (&$f)`, rather than `use ($f)`. This way, it will be able to use the updated value of the variable that results from the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is a pity, whether it is possible to consider that it is a defect of functions of an arrow? Hope in soon anything with this will make.

Comment: Arrow functions are a simplification of anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found one of the legitimate (no?) uses of `$GLOBALS`

```
$f = fn ($n) =>($n == 1) ? 1 : $n * $GLOBALS['f']($n - 1);
echo $f(5); // 120
```

**Sidenote:** what if `$n < 1` ?

Comment: Oh, my God, that's a crazy idea.

Comment: there is no `n < 1` in my problem. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive I know, but if someone passed 0 or a negative number to the function `$f(0)` the function will call itself for EVER.

Comment: this shouldn't happen, because it doesn't make sense to use this function when the value is zero. And if the value tends to one, the function will give it the same value.

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive It actually makes sense. Because  AFAIK this a factorial function and the `0!` factorial equals `1`

Answer (score 2):

As a slight variation of what @scorpion35 was saying, you could also apply currying:

```
$f = fn($f) => fn($x) => $x <= 1 
    ? $x 
    : $f($f)($x-1) * $x;
    
$factorial = $f($f);

$factorial(7); //5040
```