# Use variable by reference in arrow function

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, arrow-functions, php-7.4

PHP 7.4 introduced [Arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php). And it also introduced  implicit by-value scope binding which eliminate the need for `use` keyword.

Now if we want to use a variable out of a closure's scope by reference with a regular anonymous function we would do this:

```
$num = 10;
call_user_func(function() use (&$num) {
$num += 5;
});
echo $num; // Output: 15
```

But using an arrow function it seems impossible

```
$num = 10;
call_user_func(fn() => $num += 5);

echo $num; // Output: 10
```

So how to use `$num` variable by reference?

Comment: I think you'll have to pass it as an argument, otherwise its not visible in the functions scope. Though I'm not sure how that'll work in practice, so it might not be possible.

Comment: I presume it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewriting an anonymous function in php 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882959/rewriting-an-anonymous-function-in-php-7-4)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2) about it, it says...

> **By-value variable binding**
> As already mentioned, arrow functions use by-value variable binding. This is roughly equivalent to
> performing a use($x) for every variable $x used inside the arrow
> function. A by-value binding means that it is not possible to modify
> any values from the outer scope:
>
> ```
> $x = 1; 
> $fn = fn() => $x++; // Has no effect 
> $fn(); 
> var_dump($x); // int(1)
> ```

So it is not possible ATM.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an object to do this.

```
$state = new stdClass; 
$state->index = 1;

$fn = fn() => $state->index++; // Now, has effect.
$fn();

var_dump($x); // int(2)
```

It works because objects always pass by reference. I don't encourage you to use this but in some places it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the argument-less arrow function, but you can always define an argument inside as a reference. There is no other way using it with arrow functions.

```
$num = 10;
$fn = fn(&$num) => $num += 5;
$fn($num);

echo $num; // Output: 15
```