# PHP 7.4 recursive arrow functions

Tags: php, php-7.4

I'm experimenting with the new arrow functions in PHP 7.4 and i'm trying to create a recursive arrow function one liner. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Here's my code:

```
$factorial = fn($x) => $x === 1 ? 1 : $x * $factorial($x - 1);
```

I am getting an undefined variable here. I'm assuming the inner `$factorial` variable does not exist yet?

Error message `Notice:  Undefined variable: factorial in test.php on line 10`

Comment: Please ALWAYS show us the complete error message, not a summary of it

Comment: I don't think this is possible, sadly, because with normal closures [you'd need a reference pass in the `use` section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions), which short closures can't do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewriting an anonymous function in php 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882959/rewriting-an-anonymous-function-in-php-7-4)